# Problem to use Copilot in Vs Code with ArchLinux

Tags: visual-studio-code, archlinux, github-copilot

My pc run arch linux, i'am already using copilot with neovim and intelij idea, i tried to use with vs code but, although i was able to install the extension successfully and make it trusted by github, the code completion not work.

After the extension installation i had to log in to my Github account, it was a little hard but after some attempts i did it. I tried to use the official version of vs code founded in the AUR but nothing. In the internet, via chat gpt or in the arch wiki of vs code i couldn't find help. here my copilot extension settings:

```
{
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "yaml": false,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": false,
        "scminput": false,
        "c": true
    },
    "github.copilot.advanced": {
        
    }
}
```

my version of vs code is 1.77.3
i also report that for use the microsoft visual studio marketplace on arch's vs code, you have to install from the aur this extension: code-marketplace.

This is my first post on stack overflow so wish me luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AUR Code-OSS editor you need to remove it.

For fix this issue you can install AUR visual-studio-code-bin editor it is working.

Comment: tank you very much, now it work. I could have thought of that myself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).